# Start new chapters on odd pages using scrreprt

Tags: chapters, scrreprt

I am trying to find out how to start new chapters on odd pages. I am in use of the `scrreprt` class. I already tried adding the parameter `openright` but it does not seem to work.

My current settings are: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}`

Is there a way to achieve the above mentioned?

Comment: With options `twoside` and `open=right` (or `openright`) new chapters start on odd pages. If this does not work for you, please add a minimal working example showing the issue to your question.

Comment: `open=right` works for me. Cf. `\documentclass[british,12pt,a4paper,twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
\kant
\chapter{Ipsum}
\kant
\chapter{Dolor}
\kant
\end{document}` If it does not work for you, please show us an example document that replicates the issue. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: @moewe and @ esdd thank you, `open=right` worked using the example. There are more things to figure out, I will create a new post for this.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449155/35864. But I think this question should be closed as unclear what you are asking, since `openright` *does* work and there is nothing we can do here.

Comment: if your document where it doesn't work has `\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}` as in your previous question then that is why, that disables the chapter page opening completely.