# How to force chapters on odd pages including exceptions

Tags: chapters, scrreprt

I am trying to set my document that all chapters start exlusively on odd pages. But I have two chapters where I want a different behaviour, they need to start on the same page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{first}
    \lipsum

    \chapter*{second}
    \lipsum

    \chapter{third}
    \lipsum

    \chapter{fourth}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

What I am trying to do as far as I understood the case. I use `scrreprt` and in order to start chapters on odd pages I use the parameter `open=right`.

In order to get the two chapters on one page I include `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and the `\patchcmd{...}` command, so that all chapters markt with an asterisk (`*`) are on one page.

The result is that the first and second chapters are both right. The third chapter is false as it starts on page 4 and hence not an odd page. The fourth chapter starts rightly on page 5.

How can I achieve the above mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid patching internal KOMA-Script commands. You could use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the `style` of level `chapter` from `chapter` to `section`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}[2017/09/07]

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\specialchapters{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}%
}
\newcommand*\normalchapters{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{chapter}%
}

\begin{document}
\specialchapters
\addchap*{first}
\lipsum

\addchap*{second}
\lipsum

\normalchapters
\chapter{third}
\lipsum

\chapter{fourth}
\lipsum
\end{document
```

Or you could "clone" level `chapter` to a new level `schap` and then change the style of this level to `section`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}[2017/09/07]

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=chapter,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=1.5em
]{schap}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section
]{schap}

\begin{document}
\schap*{first}
\lipsum

\schap*{second}
\lipsum

\chapter{third}
\lipsum

\chapter{fourth}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result for both suggestions:

[image]